# Any up to date TinyMCE implementations for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

Is there a gem or plugin implementation of TinyMCE that is compatible with Rails 3.2?

I have tried [TinyMCE Hammer](http://tinymcehammer.lanalot.com/tutorials/getting_started/) and several gem implementations, but they all seem to be out of date?

Comment: TinyMCE is javascript, you shouldn't need any rails-specific framework, you could simply include the necessary files/mark up with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails). It makes it easier to manage TinyMCE, because you can just update the gem whenever TinyMCE is updated.